# How to keep subdirectory path while copying into a new file?

Tags: bash, file, directory, copy, find

With the following commands, I can search all the subdirectories from `/olddir` and copy the `*.html` files into `/newdir`:

```
find /olddir -iname "*.html" -type f -exec cp {} /newdir/ \;
```

But how do i keep the subdirectory information e.g.:

```
/olddir/some/foobar/path/abc.html
```

should copied into `/newdir` as the absolute path:

```
/newdir/some_foobar_path_abc.html
```

Assume that no subdirectory names contains underscore `_`.

**Input example directory:**

```
/olddir
  /somesubdir
    foobarfile.html
  helloworld.html
```

**Desired output:**

```
/newdir
  somesubdir_foobarfile.html
  helloword.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this `find` command:

```
find olddir -iname "*.html" -type f -exec bash -c 'f=${0#olddir/}; mv $0 newdir/${f//\//_}' {} \;
```

To see what file changes this will make, you can run this version (which echoes the commands to be run) beforehand:

```
find olddir -iname "*.html" -type f -exec bash -c 'f=${0#olddir/}; echo mv $0 newdir/${f//\//_}' {} \;
```

Example before:

```
$ tree olddir

olddir
|-- f1
|-- f2
`-- subdir
    |-- f3
    |-- subdir_three
    |   `-- f6
    `-- subdir_two
        |-- f4
        `-- f5

$ tree newdir

newdir/
```

Example with echo:

```
$ find olddir -type f -exec bash -c 'f=${0#olddir/}; echo mv $0 newdir/${f//\//_}' {} \;
mv olddir/subdir/subdir_two/f4 newdir/subdir_subdir_two_f4
mv olddir/subdir/subdir_two/f5 newdir/subdir_subdir_two_f5
mv olddir/subdir/subdir_three/f6 newdir/subdir_subdir_three_f6
mv olddir/subdir/f3 newdir/subdir_f3
mv olddir/f1 newdir/f1
mv olddir/f2 newdir/f2
```

Example after running command:

```
$ tree olddir
olddir
`-- subdir
    |-- subdir_three
    `-- subdir_two

$ tree newdir/
newdir/
|-- f1
|-- f2
|-- subdir_f3
|-- subdir_subdir_three_f6
|-- subdir_subdir_two_f4
`-- subdir_subdir_two_f5
```

Comment: and it moves my files and messed up the structure... i've to roll back my files to retrieve the original strucutre...

Comment: Apologies, I misread your original question. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `basename` and `dirname` for path.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find /root/old -iname "*.html" -type f)

for f in $files
do

dir=$(dirname $f | sed 's/^.//' | sed 's/\//_/g')
name=$(basename $f)

cp $f /root/new/"$dir"_"$name"

done
```

- Finding html files in /root/old directory.
- Getting dirname, removing first character, replacing other / to _ character.
- Getting basename.
- Copying html file to /root/new/your_old_path_filename.html

Input:

```
/root/old/oldsub1/oldsub2/test3.html
/root/old/oldsub1/test2.html
/root/old/test1.html
```

Output:

```
/root/new/root_old_oldsub1_test2.html
/root/new/root_old_test1.html
/root/new/root_old_oldsub1_oldsub2_test3.html
```